# React useEffect with AbortController not updating state properly

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, axios

I'm using React and the `useEffect` hook to fetch data from an API endpoint. I want to implement cancellation of the request using an `AbortController`, but I'm facing an issue where the state is sometimes updated with the data from the previous page.

Here's my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const signal = controller.signal;

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      setData(''); // Added this line to reset the state before sending the request

      const res = await axios.get(`/api/test?logID=${router.query.logID}`, { signal });
      setData(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.name === 'AbortError') {
        console.log('Fetch request aborted');
      } else {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  };

  if (router.query.logID) {
    fetchData();
  }

  return () => {
    controller.abort();
  };
}, [router.query.logID, setData]);
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I navigate to a different page with a different `logID`, the state sometimes gets updated with the data from the previous page's request. It seems that the cleanup function is not being called in time to prevent the state update.

For example, if I click on `logID=1` page and quickly navigate to `logID=2` page, I end up seeing data from page 1 on page 2. How can I prevent this?

I have tried adding `setData('')` before sending the API request to reset the state, but the issue still persists.

Any insights or suggestions on how to properly handle the cleanup and state updates in this scenario would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: FYI you **never** need to pass state setters like `setData` as effect hook dependencies

Comment: How are you _"navigating"_? Are you using React Router? If so, how exactly; what are your routes and what links are you using?

Comment: Try checking the signal aborted state before committing response data to state. 

    if (!signal.aborted) {
      setData(res.data);
    }